# Why does requests not return all HTML code

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am experimenting with web scraping using python and BeautifulSoup.

When performing the request the HTML is missing some data. It is valid HTML, but not all of the data is there.

The URL I am using is [this](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VOD/history?period1=1546300800&period2=1569798000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d).

In the browser I see records for dates back to Jan 2019, however the HTML returned by requests  stops at May 09 2019.

Interestingly, when I look at the page source in the browser, it also stops at May 09:

```
 data-reactid="1514"><span data-reactid="1515">May 10, 2019</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1516"><span data-reactid="1517">18.05</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1518"><span data-reactid="1519">18.33</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1520"><span data-reactid="1521">18.01</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1522"><span data-reactid="1523">18.33</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1524"><span data-reactid="1525">17.82</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1526"><span data-reactid="1527">3,894,600</span></td>
</tr><tr class="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="1528"><td class="Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)" 
data-reactid="1529"><span data-reactid="1530">May 09, 2019</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1531"><span data-reactid="1532">18.02</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1533"><span data-reactid="1534">18.11</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1535"><span data-reactid="1536">18.00</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1537"><span data-reactid="1538">18.11</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1539"><span data-reactid="1540">17.61</span></td>
<td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="1541"><span data-reactid="1542">3,986,200</span></td>
</tr></tbody><tfoot data-reactid="1543"><tr class="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) C($tertiaryColor) H(36px)" data-reactid="1544"><td class="Fz(xs)" colspan="7" data-reactid="1545"><span data-reactid="1546">*Close price adjusted for splits.</span><span class="Mstart(20px)" data-reactid="1547"><span data-reactid="1548">**Adjusted close price adjusted for both dividends and splits.</span></span></td>
</tr></tfoot></table><div class="Mstart(30px) Pt(10px)" data-reactid="1549"><span data-reactid="1550">Load
```

Can someone please show me how to get all of the data?

Comment: have a look at period1 and period2 in your req.params..

Comment: @iluvlogix I'm not sure what you mean. I have used the url exactly as copied from the browser window '... period1=1546300800&period2=1569798000 ...'

Comment: 1546300800 unix translates to 01.01.2019 - 01:00:00 so that should be fine - my thought is that maybe they limit there res on their side - nothing you can do in that case..

Comment: @iluvlogix But it works in the browser. Can they tell I'm scraping rather than browsing?

Comment: _"Interestingly, when I look at the page source in the browser, it also stops at May 09"_ -> indicates what I've mentioned - they don't provide more res than that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there within the `<script>` tags in json form. You just have to do a little bit more work to pull that out:

Your other option is there is a link that downloads the csv. You could just get it that way as well by having python read in that data from that link.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import time

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VOD/history?period1=1546300800&period2=1569798000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'

reponse = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reponse.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'root.App.main = ' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('root.App.main = ')[-1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',2)[0]

        jsondata = json.loads(jsonStr)

df = json_normalize(jsondata['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['HistoricalPriceStore']['prices'])
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime('%b %d, %Y', time.localtime(x)))
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
      adjclose  amount      close   data          date       high        low       open      type      volume
0    19.830000     NaN  19.830000    NaN  Sep 27, 2019  20.059999  19.770000  20.010000       NaN   2564100.0
1    20.049999     NaN  20.049999    NaN  Sep 26, 2019  20.120001  20.000000  20.070000       NaN   3748400.0
2    19.840000     NaN  19.840000    NaN  Sep 25, 2019  19.900000  19.700001  19.780001       NaN   2505400.0
3    19.820000     NaN  19.820000    NaN  Sep 24, 2019  19.980000  19.740000  19.969999       NaN   3894800.0
4    19.809999     NaN  19.809999    NaN  Sep 23, 2019  19.870001  19.770000  19.770000       NaN   2062500.0
5    19.850000     NaN  19.850000    NaN  Sep 20, 2019  20.080000  19.770000  20.070000       NaN   4265800.0
6    19.959999     NaN  19.959999    NaN  Sep 19, 2019  20.090000  19.820000  19.830000       NaN   3180200.0
7    19.469999     NaN  19.469999    NaN  Sep 18, 2019  19.520000  19.379999  19.490000       NaN   2691000.0
8    19.680000     NaN  19.680000    NaN  Sep 17, 2019  19.750000  19.389999  19.500000       NaN   3429700.0
9    19.709999     NaN  19.709999    NaN  Sep 16, 2019  19.840000  19.700001  19.719999       NaN   2535400.0
10   19.980000     NaN  19.980000    NaN  Sep 13, 2019  20.090000  19.910000  20.000000       NaN   3181600.0
11   19.830000     NaN  19.830000    NaN  Sep 12, 2019  19.900000  19.719999  19.830000       NaN   3406000.0
12   19.719999     NaN  19.719999    NaN  Sep 11, 2019  19.730000  19.420000  19.450001       NaN   3372700.0
13   19.420000     NaN  19.420000    NaN  Sep 10, 2019  19.480000  19.330000  19.340000       NaN   2646300.0
14   19.230000     NaN  19.230000    NaN  Sep 09, 2019  19.250000  19.030001  19.090000       NaN   3221800.0
15   19.150000     NaN  19.150000    NaN  Sep 06, 2019  19.170000  18.990000  19.020000       NaN   2657800.0
16   18.840000     NaN  18.840000    NaN  Sep 05, 2019  19.090000  18.790001  19.080000       NaN   3210600.0
17   19.110001     NaN  19.110001    NaN  Sep 04, 2019  19.139999  18.980000  19.100000       NaN   2991400.0
18   19.000000     NaN  19.000000    NaN  Sep 03, 2019  19.059999  18.840000  18.850000       NaN   3834300.0
19   18.820000     NaN  18.820000    NaN  Aug 30, 2019  18.930000  18.740000  18.889999       NaN   3523300.0
20   18.920000     NaN  18.920000    NaN  Aug 29, 2019  19.010000  18.879999  19.000000       NaN   3374000.0
21   18.680000     NaN  18.680000    NaN  Aug 28, 2019  18.700001  18.469999  18.530001       NaN   3223900.0
22   18.459999     NaN  18.459999    NaN  Aug 27, 2019  18.540001  18.420000  18.459999       NaN   2622100.0
23   18.389999     NaN  18.389999    NaN  Aug 26, 2019  18.389999  18.219999  18.299999       NaN   2138700.0
24   18.290001     NaN  18.290001    NaN  Aug 23, 2019  18.620001  18.250000  18.520000       NaN   2970200.0
25   18.350000     NaN  18.350000    NaN  Aug 22, 2019  18.469999  18.250000  18.450001       NaN   2803800.0
26   18.209999     NaN  18.209999    NaN  Aug 21, 2019  18.280001  18.139999  18.250000       NaN   2438100.0
27   17.930000     NaN  17.930000    NaN  Aug 20, 2019  18.030001  17.879999  17.990000       NaN   2679700.0
28   18.250000     NaN  18.250000    NaN  Aug 19, 2019  18.270000  18.160000  18.180000       NaN   3362500.0
29   18.340000     NaN  18.340000    NaN  Aug 16, 2019  18.360001  18.040001  18.139999       NaN   3419200.0
30   17.889999     NaN  17.889999    NaN  Aug 15, 2019  18.080000  17.820000  18.010000       NaN   2716500.0
31   17.900000     NaN  17.900000    NaN  Aug 14, 2019  18.000000  17.889999  17.910000       NaN   3322900.0
32   18.120001     NaN  18.120001    NaN  Aug 13, 2019  18.219999  17.980000  18.110001       NaN   3400000.0
33   17.850000     NaN  17.850000    NaN  Aug 12, 2019  18.059999  17.850000  18.040001       NaN   2574900.0
34   18.010000     NaN  18.010000    NaN  Aug 09, 2019  18.090000  17.969999  17.990000       NaN   2322600.0
35   18.200001     NaN  18.200001    NaN  Aug 08, 2019  18.290001  18.150000  18.219999       NaN   2942700.0
36   17.980000     NaN  17.980000    NaN  Aug 07, 2019  18.000000  17.690001  17.700001       NaN   3168700.0
37   17.860001     NaN  17.860001    NaN  Aug 06, 2019  17.910000  17.740000  17.820000       NaN   3238000.0
38   17.889999     NaN  17.889999    NaN  Aug 05, 2019  17.990000  17.799999  17.959999       NaN   2843900.0
39   18.320000     NaN  18.320000    NaN  Aug 02, 2019  18.340000  18.100000  18.240000       NaN   4736100.0
40   18.299999     NaN  18.299999    NaN  Aug 01, 2019  18.440001  18.180000  18.360001       NaN   4272900.0
41   18.120001     NaN  18.120001    NaN  Jul 31, 2019  18.400000  18.040001  18.240000       NaN   5455100.0
42   18.389999     NaN  18.389999    NaN  Jul 30, 2019  18.459999  18.290001  18.430000       NaN   3761000.0
43   18.450001     NaN  18.450001    NaN  Jul 29, 2019  18.740000  18.400000  18.700001       NaN   7287500.0
44   18.250000     NaN  18.250000    NaN  Jul 26, 2019  18.290001  17.820000  17.870001       NaN  10525700.0
45   16.379999     NaN  16.379999    NaN  Jul 25, 2019  16.480000  16.340000  16.430000       NaN   5383300.0
46   16.400000     NaN  16.400000    NaN  Jul 24, 2019  16.450001  16.250000  16.270000       NaN   3782400.0
47   16.200001     NaN  16.200001    NaN  Jul 23, 2019  16.350000  16.139999  16.200001       NaN   4483700.0
48   15.940000     NaN  15.940000    NaN  Jul 22, 2019  16.059999  15.870000  16.030001       NaN   3401000.0
49   16.110001     NaN  16.110001    NaN  Jul 19, 2019  16.180000  16.020000  16.030001       NaN   3025000.0
50   15.920000     NaN  15.920000    NaN  Jul 18, 2019  15.940000  15.750000  15.860000       NaN   3039200.0
51   15.680000     NaN  15.680000    NaN  Jul 17, 2019  15.750000  15.600000  15.680000       NaN   3174400.0
52   15.750000     NaN  15.750000    NaN  Jul 16, 2019  15.950000  15.740000  15.940000       NaN   4652300.0
53   16.309999     NaN  16.309999    NaN  Jul 15, 2019  16.360001  16.250000  16.270000       NaN   3586500.0
54   16.490000     NaN  16.490000    NaN  Jul 12, 2019  16.530001  16.420000  16.469999       NaN   2266500.0
55   16.600000     NaN  16.600000    NaN  Jul 11, 2019  16.660000  16.520000  16.620001       NaN   2157800.0
56   16.510000     NaN  16.510000    NaN  Jul 10, 2019  16.620001  16.459999  16.580000       NaN   3517500.0
57   16.549999     NaN  16.549999    NaN  Jul 09, 2019  16.650000  16.490000  16.500000       NaN   5744400.0
58   16.650000     NaN  16.650000    NaN  Jul 08, 2019  16.750000  16.610001  16.690001       NaN   3473700.0
59   16.830000     NaN  16.830000    NaN  Jul 05, 2019  16.850000  16.670000  16.790001       NaN   3234300.0
60   16.500000     NaN  16.500000    NaN  Jul 03, 2019  16.660000  16.480000  16.549999       NaN   1918400.0
61   16.209999     NaN  16.209999    NaN  Jul 02, 2019  16.260000  16.040001  16.059999       NaN   2776600.0
62   16.129999     NaN  16.129999    NaN  Jul 01, 2019  16.219999  15.960000  16.200001       NaN   2999400.0
63   16.330000     NaN  16.330000    NaN  Jun 28, 2019  16.410000  16.280001  16.360001       NaN   2657300.0
64   16.260000     NaN  16.260000    NaN  Jun 27, 2019  16.330000  16.190001  16.219999       NaN   2464400.0
65   15.950000     NaN  15.950000    NaN  Jun 26, 2019  16.040001  15.820000  15.880000       NaN   4853300.0
66   15.690000     NaN  15.690000    NaN  Jun 25, 2019  15.830000  15.610000  15.730000       NaN   6292300.0
67   16.000000     NaN  16.000000    NaN  Jun 24, 2019  16.120001  15.970000  16.070000       NaN   2445300.0
68   16.139999     NaN  16.139999    NaN  Jun 21, 2019  16.180000  16.030001  16.110001       NaN   3349200.0
69   16.309999     NaN  16.309999    NaN  Jun 20, 2019  16.330000  16.180000  16.190001       NaN   3429100.0
70   16.100000     NaN  16.100000    NaN  Jun 19, 2019  16.129999  15.910000  15.930000       NaN   2620500.0
71   16.150000     NaN  16.150000    NaN  Jun 18, 2019  16.240000  16.059999  16.059999       NaN   3290100.0
72   15.920000     NaN  15.920000    NaN  Jun 17, 2019  16.000000  15.890000  15.920000       NaN   2363900.0
73   16.000000     NaN  16.000000    NaN  Jun 14, 2019  16.170000  16.000000  16.160000       NaN   3423400.0
74   16.270000     NaN  16.270000    NaN  Jun 13, 2019  16.389999  16.230000  16.330000       NaN   2174500.0
75   16.290001     NaN  16.290001    NaN  Jun 12, 2019  16.440001  16.270000  16.400000       NaN   2170100.0
76   16.469999     NaN  16.469999    NaN  Jun 11, 2019  16.650000  16.420000  16.610001       NaN   3237200.0
77   16.420000     NaN  16.420000    NaN  Jun 10, 2019  16.469999  16.340000  16.370001       NaN   3685300.0
78   16.440001     NaN  16.440001    NaN  Jun 07, 2019  16.600000  16.370001  16.379999       NaN   4317000.0
79   16.180000     NaN  16.180000    NaN  Jun 06, 2019  16.280001  16.120001  16.280001       NaN   3736000.0
80         NaN   0.464        NaN  0.464  Jun 06, 2019        NaN        NaN        NaN  DIVIDEND         NaN
81   16.316000     NaN  16.780001    NaN  Jun 05, 2019  16.930000  16.740000  16.910000       NaN   5230900.0
82   16.422958     NaN  16.889999    NaN  Jun 04, 2019  16.959999  16.770000  16.920000       NaN   5599000.0
83   15.907615     NaN  16.360001    NaN  Jun 03, 2019  16.379999  16.209999  16.219999       NaN   2709000.0
84   15.761761     NaN  16.209999    NaN  May 31, 2019  16.340000  16.180000  16.230000       NaN   3579500.0
85   15.927060     NaN  16.379999    NaN  May 30, 2019  16.450001  16.230000  16.320000       NaN   5675800.0
86   15.839550     NaN  16.290001    NaN  May 29, 2019  16.360001  16.180000  16.320000       NaN   6556100.0
87   15.508951     NaN  15.950000    NaN  May 28, 2019  16.129999  15.940000  16.049999       NaN   5146100.0
88   15.547845     NaN  15.990000    NaN  May 24, 2019  16.020000  15.900000  16.000000       NaN   4183400.0
89   15.129736     NaN  15.560000    NaN  May 23, 2019  15.610000  15.530000  15.570000       NaN   3052500.0
90   15.411716     NaN  15.850000    NaN  May 22, 2019  15.900000  15.780000  15.800000       NaN   4160700.0
91   15.528399     NaN  15.970000    NaN  May 21, 2019  16.090000  15.920000  16.080000       NaN   5194000.0
92   15.577016     NaN  16.020000    NaN  May 20, 2019  16.059999  15.710000  15.720000       NaN   6720200.0
93   15.304758     NaN  15.740000    NaN  May 17, 2019  15.830000  15.700000  15.750000       NaN   5698000.0
94   15.431163     NaN  15.870000    NaN  May 16, 2019  16.020000  15.800000  16.000000       NaN   8469600.0
95   15.615909     NaN  16.059999    NaN  May 15, 2019  16.299999  16.049999  16.250000       NaN  10979100.0
96   15.888167     NaN  16.340000    NaN  May 14, 2019  16.580000  16.110001  16.530001       NaN  20011400.0
97   16.306276     NaN  16.770000    NaN  May 13, 2019  17.340000  16.750000  17.330000       NaN  11133100.0
98   17.823139     NaN  18.330000    NaN  May 10, 2019  18.330000  18.010000  18.049999       NaN   3894600.0
99   17.609224     NaN  18.110001    NaN  May 09, 2019  18.110001  18.000000  18.020000       NaN   3986200.0
100  17.657841     NaN  18.160000    NaN  May 08, 2019  18.330000  18.120001  18.209999       NaN   3681000.0
101  17.755075     NaN  18.260000    NaN  May 07, 2019  18.389999  18.200001  18.360001       NaN   3454800.0
102  17.823139     NaN  18.330000    NaN  May 06, 2019  18.350000  18.160000  18.240000       NaN   2226000.0
103  17.949543     NaN  18.459999    NaN  May 03, 2019  18.459999  18.299999  18.299999       NaN   2709800.0
104  17.891203     NaN  18.400000    NaN  May 02, 2019  18.459999  18.299999  18.440001       NaN   3310600.0
105  17.930098     NaN  18.440001    NaN  May 01, 2019  18.559999  18.340000  18.559999       NaN   2783700.0
106  18.007887     NaN  18.520000    NaN  Apr 30, 2019  18.590000  18.360001  18.480000       NaN   2475100.0
107  18.007887     NaN  18.520000    NaN  Apr 29, 2019  18.559999  18.430000  18.490000       NaN   2420800.0
108  17.862034     NaN  18.370001    NaN  Apr 26, 2019  18.370001  18.200001  18.270000       NaN   2936900.0
109  17.463369     NaN  17.959999    NaN  Apr 25, 2019  18.000000  17.820000  17.900000       NaN   2426000.0
110  17.473093     NaN  17.969999    NaN  Apr 24, 2019  18.150000  17.950001  18.110001       NaN   3905400.0
111  17.803692     NaN  18.309999    NaN  Apr 23, 2019  18.490000  18.209999  18.480000       NaN   3361800.0
112  17.900927     NaN  18.410000    NaN  Apr 22, 2019  18.530001  18.379999  18.510000       NaN   1968900.0
113  18.007887     NaN  18.520000    NaN  Apr 18, 2019  18.580000  18.440001  18.559999       NaN   2492400.0
114  18.192631     NaN  18.709999    NaN  Apr 17, 2019  18.790001  18.610001  18.690001       NaN   3501100.0
115  18.075951     NaN  18.590000    NaN  Apr 16, 2019  18.780001  18.549999  18.770000       NaN   2780500.0
116  18.095398     NaN  18.610001    NaN  Apr 15, 2019  18.670000  18.450001  18.520000       NaN   3599700.0
117  17.832863     NaN  18.340000    NaN  Apr 12, 2019  18.430000  18.309999  18.330000       NaN   3342700.0
118  17.580053     NaN  18.080000    NaN  Apr 11, 2019  18.219999  18.000000  18.200001       NaN   4566900.0
119  17.745352     NaN  18.250000    NaN  Apr 10, 2019  18.350000  18.230000  18.299999       NaN   3560700.0
120  17.784246     NaN  18.290001    NaN  Apr 09, 2019  18.379999  18.270000  18.360001       NaN   2397500.0
121  17.842587     NaN  18.350000    NaN  Apr 08, 2019  18.400000  18.219999  18.389999       NaN   2847100.0
122  17.842587     NaN  18.350000    NaN  Apr 05, 2019  18.400000  18.230000  18.309999       NaN   4058900.0
123  18.348207     NaN  18.870001    NaN  Apr 04, 2019  18.940001  18.780001  18.790001       NaN   2840900.0
124  18.357929     NaN  18.879999    NaN  Apr 03, 2019  18.920000  18.799999  18.799999       NaN   3666500.0
125  18.046780     NaN  18.559999    NaN  Apr 02, 2019  18.590000  18.430000  18.469999       NaN   3178200.0
126  18.085674     NaN  18.600000    NaN  Apr 01, 2019  18.680000  18.459999  18.559999       NaN   4132500.0
127  17.677288     NaN  18.180000    NaN  Mar 29, 2019  18.190001  17.969999  18.070000       NaN   4047400.0
128  17.628670     NaN  18.129999    NaN  Mar 28, 2019  18.430000  18.040001  18.410000       NaN   3990400.0
129  18.075951     NaN  18.590000    NaN  Mar 27, 2019  18.780001  18.540001  18.760000       NaN   3537000.0
130  18.357929     NaN  18.879999    NaN  Mar 26, 2019  18.910000  18.740000  18.799999       NaN   4653100.0
131  18.075951     NaN  18.590000    NaN  Mar 25, 2019  18.969999  18.520000  18.889999       NaN   6215900.0
132  18.416273     NaN  18.940001    NaN  Mar 22, 2019  19.190001  18.889999  19.129999       NaN   9118800.0
133  18.581572     NaN  19.110001    NaN  Mar 21, 2019  19.280001  19.000000  19.270000       NaN   6842300.0
134  18.737146     NaN  19.270000    NaN  Mar 20, 2019  19.400000  19.139999  19.250000       NaN   5852500.0
135  18.698252     NaN  19.230000    NaN  Mar 19, 2019  19.330000  19.170000  19.290001       NaN   3800300.0
136  18.562124     NaN  19.090000    NaN  Mar 18, 2019  19.110001  18.940001  19.070000       NaN   2958300.0
137  18.513508     NaN  19.040001    NaN  Mar 15, 2019  19.059999  18.850000  18.900000       NaN   6516900.0
138  18.075951     NaN  18.590000    NaN  Mar 14, 2019  18.650000  18.530001  18.600000       NaN   3807100.0
139  17.910650     NaN  18.420000    NaN  Mar 13, 2019  18.459999  18.200001  18.370001       NaN   6048900.0
140  17.657841     NaN  18.160000    NaN  Mar 12, 2019  18.270000  18.049999  18.100000       NaN   3867800.0
141  17.687012     NaN  18.190001    NaN  Mar 11, 2019  18.240000  17.860001  17.910000       NaN   4792100.0
142  17.336966     NaN  17.830000    NaN  Mar 08, 2019  17.910000  17.690001  17.860001       NaN   4983300.0
143  17.200838     NaN  17.690001    NaN  Mar 07, 2019  17.790001  17.520000  17.700001       NaN   4086300.0
144  17.152218     NaN  17.639999    NaN  Mar 06, 2019  17.820000  17.520000  17.820000       NaN   6604000.0
145  17.025814     NaN  17.510000    NaN  Mar 05, 2019  17.660000  17.440001  17.559999       NaN   9537400.0
146  16.597980     NaN  17.070000    NaN  Mar 04, 2019  17.440001  17.049999  17.400000       NaN  11262400.0
147  17.113325     NaN  17.600000    NaN  Mar 01, 2019  18.030001  17.559999  17.950001       NaN   5938800.0
148  17.356413     NaN  17.850000    NaN  Feb 28, 2019  17.910000  17.790001  17.850000       NaN   4310600.0
149  17.336966     NaN  17.830000    NaN  Feb 27, 2019  18.030001  17.719999  17.990000       NaN   4699500.0
150  17.492540     NaN  17.990000    NaN  Feb 26, 2019  18.129999  17.990000  18.059999       NaN   5360400.0
151  17.696735     NaN  18.200001    NaN  Feb 25, 2019  18.500000  18.160000  18.480000       NaN   4276100.0
152  17.939821     NaN  18.450001    NaN  Feb 22, 2019  18.620001  18.420000  18.530001       NaN   3426900.0
153  17.774523     NaN  18.280001    NaN  Feb 21, 2019  18.440001  18.209999  18.290001       NaN   3887000.0
154  17.998163     NaN  18.510000    NaN  Feb 20, 2019  18.620001  18.430000  18.530001       NaN   4700100.0
155  17.930098     NaN  18.440001    NaN  Feb 19, 2019  18.520000  18.200001  18.230000       NaN   4839200.0
156  17.755075     NaN  18.260000    NaN  Feb 15, 2019  18.270000  18.059999  18.129999       NaN   5955900.0
157  17.443924     NaN  17.940001    NaN  Feb 14, 2019  18.010000  17.790001  17.799999       NaN   4574700.0
158  17.434200     NaN  17.930000    NaN  Feb 13, 2019  18.090000  17.900000  18.010000       NaN   4095900.0
159  17.473093     NaN  17.969999    NaN  Feb 12, 2019  18.110001  17.910000  18.059999       NaN   4833200.0
160  17.618948     NaN  18.120001    NaN  Feb 11, 2019  18.200001  18.070000  18.190001       NaN   3322200.0
161  17.541159     NaN  18.040001    NaN  Feb 08, 2019  18.070000  17.840000  17.910000       NaN   3847700.0
162  17.550880     NaN  18.049999    NaN  Feb 07, 2019  18.290001  18.010000  18.250000       NaN   4331000.0
163  17.881479     NaN  18.389999    NaN  Feb 06, 2019  18.610001  18.360001  18.510000       NaN   5584800.0
164  17.745352     NaN  18.250000    NaN  Feb 05, 2019  18.309999  18.190001  18.260000       NaN   3373400.0
165  17.550880     NaN  18.049999    NaN  Feb 04, 2019  18.110001  17.900000  17.980000       NaN   4809200.0
166  17.706457     NaN  18.209999    NaN  Feb 01, 2019  18.240000  18.030001  18.040001       NaN   4915000.0
167  17.735628     NaN  18.240000    NaN  Jan 31, 2019  18.290001  18.020000  18.150000       NaN   6403500.0
168  17.473093     NaN  17.969999    NaN  Jan 30, 2019  17.980000  17.770000  17.900000       NaN   5634200.0
169  17.268902     NaN  17.760000    NaN  Jan 29, 2019  17.980000  17.700001  17.950001       NaN   5637500.0
170  17.366137     NaN  17.860001    NaN  Jan 28, 2019  17.980000  17.780001  17.900000       NaN   9254800.0
171  17.473093     NaN  17.969999    NaN  Jan 25, 2019  18.139999  17.860001  18.090000       NaN  10691300.0
172  18.046780     NaN  18.559999    NaN  Jan 24, 2019  18.990000  18.510000  18.969999       NaN   8141000.0
173  18.970510     NaN  19.510000    NaN  Jan 23, 2019  19.680000  19.469999  19.490000       NaN   4610000.0
174  18.649635     NaN  19.180000    NaN  Jan 22, 2019  19.260000  19.129999  19.209999       NaN   4847200.0
175  18.766315     NaN  19.299999    NaN  Jan 18, 2019  19.400000  19.200001  19.200001       NaN   5476900.0
176  18.659359     NaN  19.190001    NaN  Jan 17, 2019  19.240000  18.980000  19.000000       NaN   4374600.0
177  18.581572     NaN  19.110001    NaN  Jan 16, 2019  19.200001  18.990000  19.020000       NaN   4211700.0
178  18.513508     NaN  19.040001    NaN  Jan 15, 2019  19.139999  18.920000  18.969999       NaN   4845100.0
179  18.746870     NaN  19.280001    NaN  Jan 14, 2019  19.350000  19.120001  19.280001       NaN   6084800.0
180  19.155256     NaN  19.700001    NaN  Jan 11, 2019  19.820000  19.420000  19.490000       NaN   6235600.0
181  19.038574     NaN  19.580000    NaN  Jan 10, 2019  19.730000  19.480000  19.520000       NaN   4408000.0
182  18.970510     NaN  19.510000    NaN  Jan 09, 2019  19.580000  19.200001  19.360001       NaN   5354200.0
183  19.174702     NaN  19.719999    NaN  Jan 08, 2019  19.910000  19.610001  19.850000       NaN   5845000.0
184  19.621984     NaN  20.180000    NaN  Jan 07, 2019  20.240000  19.920000  20.000000       NaN   5996100.0
185  19.476131     NaN  20.030001    NaN  Jan 04, 2019  20.070000  19.830000  19.870001       NaN   5868300.0
186  19.096914     NaN  19.639999    NaN  Jan 03, 2019  19.820000  19.549999  19.750000       NaN   5659100.0
187  19.174702     NaN  19.719999    NaN  Jan 02, 2019  19.790001  19.190001  19.299999       NaN   5106800.0
```

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks for this. I have tried the download option and get the response {
    "finance": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "description": "Invalid cookie"
        }
    }
} They must be blocking that too

Comment: ahh ok. Looks like if you want to go that route, you'll need to use selenium as the link is rendered after. I'm not going to bother with that since I think the method above is quicker and then there is no need to simulate/open the browser